# K-mean image clustering (Matlab Code)

Tags: matlab, k-means, image-segmentation

Hello every one can some help me to segment out image using K-Mean clustering 
i need a Hello every one can some help me to segment out image using K-Mean clustering 
i need a Matlab code for this purpose 
i have got one here 'http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8379-kmeans-image-segmentation/' but i dont know how to use it kindly help me to use this code or give me some other code

i also tried that in this fashion but it did not worked for me

```
img=imread('cameraman.tif');
%imshow(img);
[mu,mask]=kmeans(img,3);
imshow(mask);
```

Comment: how to use the given existing code

Answer (score 1):

In order to execute your code, you need the Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox. Here is the working code and the clustered cameraman for 2, 4 and 8 clusters:

[image]

```
ab=imread('cameraman.tif');
ab = double(ab);

nrows = size(ab,1);
ncols = size(ab,2);
ab = reshape(ab,nrows*ncols,1);

nColors = 4;
% repeat the clustering 3 times to avoid local minima
[cluster_idx, cluster_center] = kmeans(ab,nColors,'distance','sqEuclidean', 'Replicates', 3);

pixel_labels = reshape(cluster_idx,nrows,ncols);
imshow(pixel_labels,[]);
```

Comment: The cluster_center has the centroid locations. It will be a k x 1 vector. How are these k doubles related to the physical notion of cluster centroids in the image?